# Is "wait &" ("wait ampersand") a useful (bash) shell / shell script idiom or technique?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, shell-builtin

I've "inherited" some shell scripts for Linux machines running the GNU "bash" shell. In one particular case, the machine runs GNU bash version 2.0.5b

One of those scripts has a `wait &` ("wait ampersand") instruction as part of the "for line" of a `for` loop. At first sight, that seems to be a curious/interesting idiom, but my web searches for it did not return anything relevant. `man wait` shows the "BASH_BUILTINS" ("BASH BUILTINS COMMAND") manpage, which has the following description:

```
wait [n]  
  Wait for the specified process and return its termination status.
  n may be a process ID or a job spec­ification;  if  a  job spec is given,
  all processes in that job's pipeline are waited for.  If n is not
  given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the 
  return status is zero. If n speci­fies a non-existent process or job, 
  the return status is 127.  Otherwise, the return status is the exit 
  status of the last process or job waited for.
```

By reading that part of this manpage, it seems to me that `wait &` is silently (in the background) making sure that "*all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status is zero*.". Am I right in this interpretation? Is this a common and/or useful idiom?

For added context, I'm talking about the following kind of usage in the script:

```
for file in `ls *.txt ; wait &`
do
   ...
   [cp instructions]
   ...
   [mv instructions]
   ...
   [mailx instruction]
done
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't imagine any reason to write this code, and I'm not quite sure what the person who wrote this code was trying to achieve. `wait` here does nothing -- from its perspective, there *are* no child processes, so it will just exit immediately and basically act as a noop (`wait` itself executes in a child process due to command substitution, but that's unrelated).

As an aside, [parsing the output of ls is quite fragile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, consider just doing this:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    ...
done
```